# Filter array of objects with nested objects by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have an array of objects

```
[
{
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1654000036,
        "nanoseconds": 204000000
    },
    "lyrics": {
        "liryc-1-b": "Some example lyrics verse 1",
        "liryc-1-a": "Some example lyrics verse 2"
    },
    "category": "maculele",
    "title": "asdasd"
},
{
    "category": "corridos",
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1653936021,
        "nanoseconds": 438000000
    },
    "lyrics": {
        "liryc-1-b": "lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor ",
        "liryc-1-a": "lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor "
    }
 }
]
```

and I'd like to search if the title and lyrics contain a search quote.

I already know how to search by title only but I need to search by lyrics as well

```
<SongbookContainer>
            {query === ''
                ? songs.map((song, i) => <SongPreview key={i} song={song} />)
                : songs
                      .filter(song => song.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
                      .map((filteredSong, i) => <SongPreview key={i} song={filteredSong} />)}
        </SongbookContainer>
```

how can I search by both title and lyrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Along with the song `title` you also need to check the same condition with the values of `lyrics` object. You can get values of `lyrics` object by passing object to `Object.values()`. And with `Array.some()` you can evaluate if there is any element satisfying condition. As `Array.some()` returns a boolean it will make it easy to check.**

fix would be.

```js
const songs = [
{
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1654000036,
        "nanoseconds": 204000000
    },
    "lyrics": {
        "liryc-1-b": "Some example lyrics verse 1",
        "liryc-1-a": "Some example lyrics verse 2"
    },
    "category": "maculele",
    "title": "asdasd"
},
{
    "category": "corridos",
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1653936021,
        "nanoseconds": 438000000
    },
    "lyrics": {
        "liryc-1-b": "lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor ",
        "liryc-1-a": "lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor "
    }
 }
]

const query = 'dolor';

songs.filter(song => song.title?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || Object.values(song.lyrics)?.some(l => l.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))).map(r => console.log(r));
```

Also, you need to check if the song title is null or undefined as a second object from songs missing `title` property. You can do that with [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Thank you very much! Working perfectly fine! :)  Using map, filter, includes, some and values methods in one line gives me a headache haha thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the `lyrics` object keys or values using the `some` method:

```
<SongbookContainer>
  {query === ''
    ? songs.map((song, i) => <SongPreview key={i} song={song} />)
    : songs
        .filter((song) => {
          return song.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) && 
            // If you need to filter by key
            Object.keys(song.lyrics).some(lyricKey => lyricKey.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) 
            // Or, If you need to filter by value
            Object.values(song.lyrics).some(lyricValue => lyricValue.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
        })
        .map((filteredSong, i) => <SongPreview key={i} song={filteredSong} />)}
</SongbookContainer>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but it's work.

```js
const query = "title";

/**
* tools to parse data any data to string and find correspond word.
*/
function wordExist(data, word) {
  if (!data || !word) {
    return false;
  }
  const parse = JSON.stringify(data);
  return parse.includes(word);
}

// use like this in your current filter
  array.filter(
    (song) => wordExist(song.title, query) || wordExist(song?.lyrics, query)
  )
);
```